# Contrbution Summary report on Average Contribution?

Tags: contributions

I am looking for a report that list all contacts who have donated an average between 100 and 200 in a time frame. So if a contact has donated 3 times in the period, one donation of 100 and two donations of 150 I would expect to see that contact.

I have played with the Contribution Summary report as it has a filter 'Contribution Average' and the option to add the donor name. It does not do what I hoped though? The donor name is just confusing on that report I guess.

Any suggestions or someone who has achieved this?

I need this on CiviCRM 4.4 but have also tried on 4.6 with the same results.

Answer (score 2):

the [summary field extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields) may be your friend allthough you may hav to tweek/extend it a little bit when it comes to time frames.